# Transformation of known analog PI controller settings to a digital PID controller setting

Tags: digital-logic, analog, pid-controller

I have used an analog PI controller ([New Focus LB1005-S](https://www.newport.com/p/LB1005-S)) so far to lock the repetition rate of a mode-locked laser using a piezo as actuator on the laser cavity length.

The transfer function of the controller is given as
[image]

The PI controller settings, namely [image] and the integration time [image] are already optimized for our plant and known.

We now plan on using a digital Lock-In Amplifier ([Zurich Instruments UHFLI](https://www.zhinst.com/europe/en/products/uhfli-lock-in-amplifier)) as a replacement.

As we already know a working set of PI settings, we would like to "translate" them to our new controller. I am aware that there exist methods which use the [z-transformation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Controllers_and_Compensators#Digital_PID) to relate an analog transfer function (s-domain) to a digital transfer function (z-domain), but I am not sure, how this can help me (if it can).

In the analog case, my error signal was a voltage, which I got from mixing my reference with my controlled variable. The output of my PI controller was once again a voltage. Therefore, e.g. my linear gain was simply given as [image].

In the digital case I get a phase offset from my demodulator as error signal, telling me about the  phase relation of reference and controlled variable. The linear gain is therefore given as [image].

Is there an (ideally: rather simple) way of transforming the settings, so that I can use the "digital equivalent" of the already known and tested analog set?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a simpler approach, but here’s how you can do it by mapping it into the Z-Transform.

1. Perform the Z-Transform mapping of your choice (bilinear transform is pretty popular).
2. Use the Z-Transform to find the residues of the system.
3. Use the residues to find the difference equation of the equivalent digital system. Make sure to pay attention to the region of convergence.
4. Implement your new difference equation in software.

The bilinear transform isn’t always pretty, so this is easier said than done, but it’s one possible approach if you can’t find anything else. Good luck.

---

**EDIT**

I just read the question closer and noticed the error signal for the new system is a phase offset instead of a voltage. This means there’s an unknown relationship between the phase offset and the previous error voltage that changes the system as a whole. This makes transforming the system more difficult. Hopefully there’s some other advice that can be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but yes, actually the issue is, that one also would need to map the different input to the digital version, not only the PID params I guess ... :/